# Is it possible to use CSS to ensure text is always displayed the same way?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Qur'an app (Qur'an is the holy text for Muslims), and there are a number of such apps on the market already, but the one I have in mind is a bit special.

There are two types of Qur'an apps: the types that look exactly like a certain version of the paper copy (i.e. page 1 looks exactly the same in all copies, regardless of the publisher). The problem with these apps is that they use images to ensure each page looks exactly the same, which is unnecessary bandwidth and also is not very flexible. This also does not allow the user to select individual verses (to say, get the translation or to hear the recitation of that particular verse).

Example: 
[image: Mushaf Madina]

The other type of Qur'an is the type that does use text, and allows for the flexibility of verse selection. The caveat being of course, that there are no "pages," the apps tend to merely have each verse on its own line (wrapping around if necessary).

Example:
[image: iQuran]

The problem with the second type of Qur'an app is that the Qur'an is one of the most widely memorized books. And one of the ways people memorize it is by location on the page.

So I want to combine these two worlds. I want to use text to render the Qur'an, but I also want it to look exactly like the paper version, page for page, line for line.

Would that be possible?

This is what I have (very rough):
http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/wGJzm/1/

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arabz;
    src: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17145089/tyaslab/KFGQPCUthmanTahaNaskh.ttf);
}

p {
    font-family: Arabz;
    text-align: justify; /*To justify the text, all the books do this */
    font-size: 26px; 
}
```

Thanks!

Edit 2: Upon further reflection, the defining factor would be finding a font. As there is no single pattern that governs the script of the Qur'an (sometimes the same word can be written differently depending on context), I don't think a font exists for this. Using any other font would work theoretically, in context of this question, but it would not be something that someone would use since it does not mimic the physical text.

Comment: The answer I'd give is yes, but as it is, this question is too broad.

Comment: How can I make it more specific?

Comment: I agree with Jeremy but I guess your solution would simply be to find the right font and design for it

Comment: I would add to Jeremy's comment that you should show what you have tried doing, and point out your specific problem.

Comment: The prime functionality I want to implement is verse selection, which isn't possible on the static, image-based apps.

Comment: OK I understand. I'll update the question with what I've tried and what I've come up with.

Comment: @abustamam I'm not familiar with the Quran, but isn't the point of verses so that you don't need page numbers?

Comment: @Jeremy In general yes. I'm not too concerned with the page numbers though as much as I am with each page looking the same. The way most people memorize the Quran is something like "oh this part's on the right page somewhere in the middle, and I remember the top of the left page being this." So it doesn't require page _numbers_ per se, but it still requires pages. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/wGJzm/

It might be a problem with RTL languages, but it looks nothing like it's supposed to. I have a Quranic font in ttf form, so I will try to implement that too.

Comment: @abustamam So people memorize based on spatial location? So your main question is "how can I get pages/page sizes" to be consistent on any device? You'll need to set a static width and height of each page.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and static width/height makes sense. But I tried `text-align: justify` and it didn't really justify. To make things worse the lines aren't even on a line [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/wGJzm/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can approach the image quality by using a few CSS Properties.

```
body {
    background-image: url(BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL_HERE);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

then

```
text-align: justify /*To justify the text, all the books do this */
font-size: CUSTOME_SIZEpx /* With justify and this you can control very rigorously your page content to fit exactly as the original book does */
```

You will have by the way the verse selection as you are using the text approach.

Comment: What does background-image do?

Comment: It is to get a background image for your page.

Comment: Place this rule in the body of your page

Comment: Should the background image be the image of the page?

Comment: Yes indeed it should.

Comment: This is what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/wGJzm/2/

Now I have text overlaying image. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: For the background-image use a blank one.

Comment: It still didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/wGJzm/3/ I think the issue I should fix first is the fact that the lines are not straight.